# C + GTK + WEBKIT program does not compile: fatal error: webkit2/webkit2.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c, webkit

On a Linux Mint 64-bit PC

This C program does not compile:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <webkit2/webkit2.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    return 0;
}

gcc `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` -o hello hello.c `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0`
```

The compile error message is: hello.c:2:29: fatal error: webkit2/webkit2.h: No such file or directory

I've installed every webkit library I can find and I continue to get this error message!

I have searched and found on my Linux Mint PC:
/usr/include/webkitgtk-4.0/webkit2/webkit2.h

I think the gcc compile command does not include info about webkit2.

Comment: You may have the webkit1 api configured for webkit-gtk. Look in your pkgconfig dir for webkitgtk (or is it gtkwebkit) ... once you know the exact name of the .pc file you can add a similar pkgconfig command.  You may need to change your includes as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to add some include folders explicitely.
For example, in the case of webkit2
gcc -I 
Try to find it ith find or locate if the db is updated.

Answer (score 0):

The following gcc compile command seems to work:

```
gcc `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0 webkit2gtk-4.0` -o hello hello.c `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0 webkit2gtk-4.0`
```